# convert field text to List (text) drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a field that is type text and I want to convert it to type List (text) in Drupal 7. I can't simply change the value, as it won't let me, is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no easy way, no. As far as I can tell these are the manual DB changes you'll need to make:

1. In `field_config` change the `type` column to 'list_text' and `module` column to 'list' for your field.
2. Then you'll need to change the serialised array in the `data` column to match that of a list type (it'll have the settings for text types at the moment obviously). There's no easy way to show you how to do it here, the best way would be to compare the serialised array with one for a different field of a list type, then you'll be able to see what values you need to remove/change. The `allowed_values` array under `settings` will be where you put your list's values. Once that's changed, re-serialise it and put it back in the `data` column for your field.
3. After that remove any columns from your field's `field_data` and `field_revision` tables that begin with `field_myfield_` but **aren't** `field_myfield_value` (the list type still needs that column).
4. Add an index to those tables for the `value` column.
5. Clear your caches

I must warn that's completely untested it just seems to make sense looking at the table structures, it'd be a good idea to take a back up of the three tables you'll be playing with just in case.

Comment: I also had to change the widget type, which you can either do by editing the data directly in `field_config_instance`, or editing the field and selecting "Select" or "Checkboxes" as the widget type.



Also as a tip, I found it easiest to make the select field first and use that serialized data to edit the existing column.  You basically only need to change the name (and the character lengths for those entries) and the ID.

Answer (score 5):

I just wrote some code that should handle this for you in my [Helper module](https://www.drupal.org/project/helper): http://cgit.drupalcode.org/helper/tree/lib/FieldChangeHelper.php?h=7.x-1.x

```
FieldChangeHelper::changeType('my_text_field_name', 'list_text');
```

It should work fine for most simple cases and fields, but should be tested thoroughly. It also currently doesn't update any field formatters, so you'll want to review the display configuration for the field after running this.

Comment: I don't see anything in here about adjusting the foreign keys. That's the bit I'm stuck on. Does this account for moving MUL from value to format?

Comment: Well, I tried it and the foreign keys are indeed updated. I still have no idea how to make this work in my own custom module, but I guess I can use this for now. DaveReid to the rescue :)